# How to connect button to main activity in Android studio?

Tags: android, main-activity

I think that my question is easy but I have no idea how to solve it.

I made a java class (test_class) and `xml` file for this class. In `xml` file I made a button and its work correctly in test_class, but I have to use it in `MainActivity`. 
I made this button public and made object of this class, but the button is null. I also tried to make button from main activity

`Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logButton)`

but  its also null.

How can I solve this problem?

thanks in advance!

Comment: post your code in here first

Comment: The view is not found in the active layout or there is no layout set (`setContentView`)

Comment: instead of making a new Java Class, go to Activity and select Empty Activity

Answer (score 1):

In MainActivity.java make a public void method that takes a View parameter. 
e.g.

```
public void buttonPressed(View view) {
     // do stuff
}
```

In activity_main.xml - in your button node add

```
<Button
   ...
   android:onClick="buttonPressed"
   ...
/>
```

And now they're wired.